# Subjunctive mood in the past tense

Tags: verbs, conjunctions, subjunctives

If I organise an event and allow only people who bought a ticket, how do I construct a sentence with "require" and the subjunctive mood to express the requirement?

1. *We require that everybody bought a ticket.*
2. *We require everybody to have bought a ticket.* (Well, this is not really a subjunctive mood as far as I concern, so I would like to avoid this style. Nonetheless, I'm interested how correct and natural it is)
3. *We require that everybody have bought a ticket.*
4. Another option?

Does the answer change if the requirement changes into "people who have ever been to Czechia"?

Comment: I think you mean *subjunctive*. The present tense of *require*  is always going to conflict with past tenses of *buy*. I can't vouch for Czech.

Comment: Correct, I meant "subjunctive", thanks ;) I'll correct it.

Comment: This is a bit of an XY problem:  The solution to most questions about the subjunctive is "don't use the subjunctive" It has been virtually dropped from English grammar. Instead "You must have a ticket" or something like that.  English works with modals, not moods.

Answer (score 1):

First I would change the "bought a ticket" to "have a ticket" or "a ticket is needed". After all, you probably don't care who bought it, but only who has one when they get there :)

A friendly reminder would be "A ticket is needed for admission" (no ticket, you don't get in)

A more stern reminder would be "A ticket is required to get in" (like a teacher telling her students "This book is required reading to pass")

Comment: A funny one, because I couldn't stop thinking about it :)

lord of the rings: "(Gandalf)Thou shall not pass! unless thou has a ticket"

Comment: Thank you, although this is just an example I made up. I'm not organising any event, I wanted to enquire about grammar :D

Answer (score 1):

The present subjunctive is the same as the infinitive form of the verb, and doesn't change according to the subject.  You form it like this:

> We require that everyone buy a ticket.
>
> We require that he buy a ticket (non subjunctive would be *he buys*).
>
> We require that everyone be seated at 10pm.
>
> We require that he be seated at 10pm (using *be* to illustrate).

The past subjective is the same as the past tense form that is *not* the third person singular, even if the subject is third person singular.

> We required that he were seated at 10pm (not *was*).
>
> We required that he have his ticket ready at 10pm (not *has*).
>
> We required that everyone bought a ticket (*bought* is same for all subjects in past tense form).

Structures with *to have + X*, *to do + X* and *to be + X* follow the same rules; the verb that changes is *have*, *do*, or *be* like it would in past or present tenses.

> We wish that she do look for the lost item before filing a report (though this would probably be "We do wish that she look for the lost item ...")
>
> We require that he have bought his ticket by 10pm (not *has bought*).
>
> We require that the ticket be bought by 10pm (not *was bought*).

Comment: "We require that the ticket be bought by 10pm (not was bought)" - but why not "were bought"?
Thank you; so from my guesses the correct ones would be both 1. and 3., right? What about the Czechia example?